# Multiple hash algorithms

Tags: hash, password-cracking, hashcat

Using Hashcat, is it possible to crack hashes using nested, or combinations, of algorithms?

As a simple example of what I am looking to do, consider `sha1(md5('password'))` or `md5(sha1('salt') + md5('password'))`.

Comment: I am not asking about the security of using nested algorithms, I know that it is not good to do. Nor is it good to use `sha1` or `md5` since they are weak and easily cracked compared to `bcrypt`, `sha-256`, and `sha-512`. My question is if hashcat can combine algorithms to execute against a hash file, which your linked question does not answer.

Comment: Your first example is simply `--hash-type 4700`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it has been mentioned in the comments, your first example is actually covered by hashcat (hash type 4700). However, it is not possible to create your own, custom hash type "on the fly".